# Node projects with Underscore template delimeters conflicting in EJS views

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, underscore.js, ejs

Have backbone project using underscore templates. Using nodejs on the server and rendering views with EJS. Underscore templates use the same delimiters as EJS and because the underscore templates are in my .ejs views as inline script tags I am getting errors.
I tried the below solution:

```
app.set('view options', {
    open: '{{',
    close: '}}'
});
```

It still appears to be trying to render the underscore template and throwing an error:

```
<h2><%= title %></h2>

title is not defined
```

It seems using a custom delimiter in EJS just adds to the type of tags that are accepted instead of changing them. I also couldn't find a way to spit out raw html like you can in haml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [underscore documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#template) indicates to use the _.templateSettings object to override the way the delimiters are used. So something like this:

```
_.templateSettings = {
    evaluate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g,
    interpolate: /\{\{=(.+?)\}\}/g
};
```

Comment: Ahhh why didn't I figure this out. Makes perfect sense to do it this way. Thanks works.